# Получить аргументы корутины

Tags: python

Необходимо получать адрес удачного и неудачного подключения

```
result = ''
for result_future in asyncio.as_completed([loop.create_connection(asyncio.Protocol, host=ip[0], port=ip[1]) for ip in ips]):
        try:
            result = await result_future
            con = con + 1
            print(result[0].get_extra_info('peername'), ' OK')
        except:
            print(inspect.getcoroutinelocals(result_future))
            fail = fail + 1
            print(result[0].get_extra_info('peername'), ' FAIL')
```

Когда я вывожу `except`, то получаю последний адрес с успешным подключением, который был заброшен в `result` ДО `except`, а нужен тот, к которому не смог подключиться

Вытащил вот такой трейсбек

```
(base) C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\intersvyaz>python test.py asd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 43, in crawl
    result = await result_future
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 533, in _wait_for_one
    return f.result()  # May raise f.exception().
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 959, in create_connection
    raise exceptions[0]
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 946, in create_connection
    await self.sock_connect(sock, address)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 554, in sock_connect
    return await self._proactor.connect(sock, address)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 732, in _poll
    value = callback(transferred, key, ov)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 524, in finish_connect
    ov.getresult()
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 1225] Удаленный компьютер отклонил это сетевое подключение
```

**UPDATE**

Решил оставить вариант с оберткой, т.к. он мне более понятен

```
async def connect(loop, ip, port):
    address = (ip, port)
    result = loop.create_connection(asyncio.Protocol, host=ip, port=port)
    try:
        await result
        return True, address
    except:
        return False, address


async def main(loop, future):
    ips = await future
    for result in asyncio.as_completed([connect(loop, ip[0], ip[1]) for ip in ips]):
        res = await result
        if res[0] is True:
            print(res[1], 'OK')
        else:
            print(res[1], 'FAIL')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В result лежит результат предыдущей корутины, ибо исключение рейзится до операции присваивания. Напиши `except Exception as e:` и вытаскивай нужные данные из исключения, или сделай функцию-обёртку над `loop.create_connection` и обрабатывай исключения в ней.

Comment: Вот с `except Exception as e:` мне понравился вариант, правда он отдает мне только номер и текст ошибки, а не объект с данными